# Convert given Datetime to Timestamp in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate. From the UI I'm getting the datetime as `2019-04-29 19:00:00`. The same value will be stored in my Oracle database but it is being saved as `2019-04-29 07:00:00`.

In Database camp_start_time Datatype is Timestamp

Adding code snippet:

```
{ "camp_id":292,"camp_name":
"Tata","camp_desc":"Tata","camp_type": 1,"camp_start_time":"2019-04-29 19:00:00"} 

@Entity public class Campaign_Sms implements Serializable{ 
@Column(name = "CAMP_START_TIME") private Date camp_start_time; }
```

Comment: Adding code snippet:  {
"camp_id":292,"camp_name":"Tata","camp_desc":"Tata","camp_type": 1,"camp_start_time":"2019-04-29 19:00:00"}    

    @Entity
public class Campaign_Sms implements Serializable{

@Column(name = "CAMP_START_TIME")
private Date camp_start_time;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` annotation with it.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date camp_start_time;
```

`TemporalType.DATE` annotation value omit the time, as well as `TemporalType.TIME` exclude the date. Check the document [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#DATE).

**UPDATE**

Output format should be this **`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a`** and if output required as it is format should be **`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`**.

Comment: Thanks sachith for reply.Still I could not able to get SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
java.util.Date date1  = sdf.parse(dt);
System.out.println("After SimpleDateFormat --"+date1);
String pattrn=sdf.format(date1);
System.out.println("After Apply pattern --"+pattrn);

O/P:
After SimpleDateFormat --Mon Apr 29 19:00:00 IST 2019
After Apply pattern --2019-04-29 07:00:00

Comment: if you're parsing `2019-04-29 19:00:00`, your input pattern should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Once you use `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` (note simple `hh`) pattern, it won't support `24h` based time format and only support `12h` time. Then you have to use `AM/PM` in the time. So, in order to support that new output, format should be **`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a`** and it's give you `2019-04-29 07:00:00 PM`

Comment: After updating input pattern yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and TemporalType.TIMESTAMP, still record is being persisted as 29/APR/19 7:00:00. PM.Could you please help me on this

Comment: If the database keeping in that format, I think, that won't be a problem as long as when you fetch back from the DB your time correctly being fetched without any data lose. I guess you database field data type is DATETIME or something (depends on the database). If that so, you don't need to worry about the value in the database as long you get the right value out. Just check with your program saving an fetching a value whether you get the same value as you inserted.

Answer (score 0):

use the @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) annotation with it.

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date camp_start_time;
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for reply.Still I could not able to get SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); java.util.Date date1 = sdf.parse(dt); System.out.println("After SimpleDateFormat --"+date1); String pattrn=sdf.format(date1); System.out.println("After Apply pattern --"+pattrn); O/P: After SimpleDateFormat --Mon Apr 29 19:00:00 IST 2019 After Apply pattern --2019-04-29 07:00:00